# RemoveAll inside foreach with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I can see why this is allowed:

```cs
foreach (var paralelos in ParalelosSeleccionadosTemp)
{
    foreach (var horario in paralelos.Horarios)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < horario.DetallesHorario.Count; i++)
        {
            if (feriados.Contains(horario.DetallesHorario[i].Fecha.Value))
            {
                horario.DetallesHorario.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but how about this?

```cs
ParalelosSeleccionadosTemp
    .ForEach(p => p.Horarios.ToList()
        .ForEach(q => q.DetallesHorario.ToList()
            .RemoveAll(x => feriados.Contains(x.Fecha.Value))));
```

I don't understand why this fails and doesn't remove any item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates a copy of the collection. Thus the original remains unaffected.

All you need to do for the second snippet to work is to remove the unnecessary call to `ToList()`:

```
ParalelosSeleccionadosTemp
    .ForEach(p => p.Horarios.ToList()
        .ForEach(q => q.DetallesHorario
            .RemoveAll(x => feriados.Contains(x.Fecha.Value))));
```

That of course will work only if `DetallesHorario` is of type `List<T>`. Otherwise you need to tweak this to use appropriate method (or create one) to remove elements from this collection.

Note that also if `Horarios` is a `List<T>` then the first call to `ToList()` is also obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

The `.ToList()` creates a new list and modify it and therefor your list isn't updated.

The way to do it is the first option, or removing the `.ToList()`

Comment: "If you remove it, it will fail from concurrency issues"  No, it won't.  It will in fact just work as intended.